# nested setInterval going into negative numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My nested setInterval (in breakValueBegins()) keeps counting down and eventually goes into negative numbers, despite being a condition that prevents it (I double checked that the if condition was inside setInterval and that the loop was set up properly. It´s also not an async problem, because otherwise the Interval would never begin). I don´t know why. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    breakSession:5,
    session:25,
    timer: 1500,
    isPaused:true,
    breakValue:300
}
this.handleSession = this.handleSession.bind(this);
this.handleTimer=this.handleTimer.bind(this);
}



handleSession(event){
const id= event.target.id;
let breakvar= this.state.breakSession;
let sessionvar= this.state.session;
let isPaused=this.state.isPaused;

if(isPaused && id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59){
this.setState((state) => ({
breakSession: this.state.breakSession +1, breakValue:this.state.breakValue + 60}))}

else if (isPaused && id==="break-decrement" && breakvar>1){
this.setState((state) => ({
breakSession: this.state.breakSession -1, breakValue:this.state.breakValue - 60}))}

else if(isPaused && id==="session-increment" && sessionvar <=59){
this.setState((state) => ({
session: this.state.session +1, timer: this.state.timer + 60}))}

else if (isPaused && id==="session-decrement" && sessionvar>1){
this.setState((state) => ({
session: this.state.session -1, timer:this.state.timer - 60}))}

}

breakValueBegins() {
  clearInterval(this.Interval);
  this.newInterval = setInterval(() => {
      let breakValue = this.state.breakValue;
      if (breakValue > 0) {
        this.setState({
          breakValue: this.state.breakValue - 1,
          isPaused: false
        })
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.newInterval)}
    }, 10)
}

handleTimer(evt) {
  const id = evt.target.id;
  let isPaused = this.state.isPaused;
  clearInterval(this.Interval)
  this.Interval = setInterval(() => {
    let timer = this.state.timer;
    if (timer > 0) {
      this.setState({
        timer: this.state.timer - 1,
        isPaused: false
      })
    }
    if (id === "reset") {
      clearInterval(this.Interval);
      this.setState((state) => ({
        session: 25,
        timer: 1500,
        breakSession: 5,
        isPaused: true
      }))
    }
    if (!isPaused) {
      clearInterval(this.Interval);
      this.setState((state) => ({
        isPaused: true
      }))
    }
    if (timer === 0) {
      this.breakValueBegins()
    }
  }, 10)
}



Clock(stateProp){
    let minutes = Math.floor(this.state.timer / 60);
    let seconds = this.state.timer - minutes * 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display breakValue={this.state.breakValue} breakSession={this.state.breakSession} displayTime={this.Clock()} session={this.state.session}/>
                <p id="break-label">Break length</p>
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="break-increment"/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="break-decrement"/>
                <p id="session-label">Session length</p>
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="session-increment" />
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="session-decrement"/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleTimer} id="start_stop"/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleTimer} id="reset"/>
            </div>
)
}
```

Comment: See I was wrong...so what was it then?

Comment: Well silly me - setState() is asynchronous inside event handlers.

Comment: I don´t know, that´s why I´m asking.

Comment: Doesn´t seem like an async problem, because everything works perfectly: it just keeps going down after the count has reached 0 (if state wasn´t set, setInterval wouldn´t even begin).

Comment: You mean it never stops declining. I misunderstood, I thought you meant it went negative and stopped.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is that when you declare `breakvalue` it is never being reassigned so if when you call `breakValueBegins` your variable will remain the same value as this.state.breakValue causing infinite decrements.

try something like this

```
breakValueBegins() {
  clearInterval(this.Interval);
  this.newInterval = setInterval(() => {
      let breakValue = this.state.breakValue;
      if (breakValue > 0) {
        this.setState({
          breakValue: this.state.breakValue - 1,
          isPaused: false
        })
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.newInterval)
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Why did this happen though? What changed? I´m trying to understand.

Comment: on every interval, you are fetching `breakValue` as appose to fetching it one when the function is called and never updating it.